# Unable to create IONIC project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

I am getting following error while creating new project whith ionicFramework, any one have idea how to resolve it.

```
DOWNLOADING: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip

C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic.js:256
      if<res.statusCode !==200> {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
  atRequest._callback(C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic.js:256
ic\lib\ionic.js:257:13)
  at self.callback (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic.js:256
ic\lib\ionic.js:129:22)
  at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:239:10)
  at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
  at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at SocketPair.<anonymous>(tls.js:1384:19)
  at SocketPair.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at SocketPair.maybeInitFinished(tls.js:977:10)
```

Comment: Make sure you are connected to net, and If problem still persists then update your ionic and cordova versions.

Comment: my ionic and cordova are the last version and I was connected to the internet wen I got this Error!

Answer (score 5):

Update your version of the ionic CLI tool first. Alternatively you could manually start the app.

1. Download the base app and unzip into your directory. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base
2. Download the blank template and merge files into the same directory. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-blank
3. Run `bower install` to make sure bower assets are up to date
4. Run `npm install` to install assets for gulp to build sass (optional if you don't use sass)

Thats just what the `ionic start` command does in a nutshell.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have ***'tutorial'*** in your *Ionic Starter templates* :

- `ionic start --list`

If It's not in the list, you must add it to the list by ***Updating*** your Ionic Framework:

- Update Ionic CLI : `sudo npm install -g ionic`
- Update Ionic Library : `ionic lib update`
- Update Apache Cordova : `sudo npm install -g cordova`