# unable to grab wrapper project: undefined in start project ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I Got this error "unable to grab wrapper project: undefined" in start project ionic, when I tried to create a new project in ionic framework, can anyboby help me ?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I was having a problem with my proxy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
PROXY=http://myproxy.com:8081 ionic start myApp
```

If you have a username and password

```
PROXY=http://username:password@myproxy.com:8081 ionic start what
```

Comment: If it does not work for you, another way is to manually create an ionic probject, as said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721917/unable-to-create-ionic-project

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with ionic installation.

Go thoroughly through [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) doc:

1. Install cordova if you haven't

   npm install -g cordova
2. Install ionic

   npm install -g ionic

Notice any permission related issues while installing. Make sure there were no issues (Errors generally has tag `ERR`)

Good luck!

Comment: I have the same issue but no errors in the install.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this issue the following website helped me out - http://www.jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/04/02/Ionic-Framework-Getting-ionic-start-appName-Working-Behind-a-Proxy.aspx

The error was being caused by proxy issues. As it looks like Ionic doesn't pick up the proxy from either node or git. So I followed the instructions (Step 1) on the link and that resolved my initial error.

I also had to additionally install Plugman on top of Cordova:

```
npm install -g plugman
```

And then also add the proxy setting to plugman:

```
plugman config set proxy http://yourproxy.com
```